# What could be worng in my middleware test (jest)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, jestjs

This is the middleware function I want to test:

```
export default function validateReqBodyMiddleware(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  const { name, email }: RequestBody = req.body;
  let errors: iError[] = [];

  if (!validator.isEmail(email.trim())) errors.push({error: "invalid email", invalidField: "email"});
  if (validator.isEmpty(name.trim())) errors.push({error: "empty name", invalidField: "name"});
  
  if (errors.length) return res.status(Status.BadRequest).json(errors);
  next();
}
```

The test is written as follows:

```
import validateRequestBody from "../../middlewares/validateRequestBody.middleware";
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";

describe("validateRequestBody middleware", () => {
  let mockRequest: Partial<Request>;
  let mockResponse: Partial<Response>;
  let nextFunction: NextFunction = jest.fn();

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockRequest = {};
    mockResponse = {
      status: jest.fn(),
      json: jest.fn(),
    };
  });

  test("wrong email format", async () => {
    const expectedResponse = [{ error: "invalid email", invalidField: "email" }];

    mockRequest = {
      body: {
        name: "John Doe",
        email: "test"
      }
    }

    validateRequestBody(
      mockRequest as Request,
      mockResponse as Response,
      nextFunction
    );

    expect(mockResponse.status).toBeCalledWith(400);
    expect(mockResponse.json).toBeCalledWith(expectedResponse);
  });
});
```

The test results:

```
 FAIL  src/tests/unitTests/test_validateRequestBody.middleware.test.ts
  validateRequestBody middleware
    ✕ wrong email format (2 ms)

  ● validateRequestBody middleware › wrong email format

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'json')

      23 |   if (validator.isEmpty(name.trim())) errors.push({error: "empty name", invalidField: "name"});
      24 |   
    > 25 |   if (errors.length) return res.status(Status.BadRequest).json(errors);
         |                                                          ^
      26 |   next();
      27 | }

      at validateRequestBody (src/middlewares/validateRequestBody.middleware.ts:25:58)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/tests/unitTests/test_validateRequestBody.middleware.test.ts:27:24)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.216 s, estimated 2 s
Ran all test suites.
```

I think that occurs because of the methods .status() and .json() are concatenated. When I remove one or another the test pass. I have no idea in which way I can solve this. Could anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: As you already worked out, _"that occurs because of the methods .status() and .json() are concatenated"_. `res.status(Status.BadRequest)`, like any unconfigured `jest.fn()`, returns `undefined`. `undefined`, as the error message tells you, has no `json` (or any other) property. Test doubles, as an _absolute minimum_, need to have the same interface as the thing they're replacing, which means `status` needs to return an object with a `json` method. But fundamentally this is the problem with mocking what you don't own - you end up with a complex test double that couples to implementation detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) in:

```
if (errors.length) return res.status(400).json(errors);
```

While your mock has:

```
mockResponse = {
  status: jest.fn(),
  json: jest.fn(),
};
```

What you want to do is to have:

```
mockResponse = {
  status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  json: jest.fn(),
};
```

So your [`.status()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.status) can return [`.json()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json)